# $\mathbb{Q}$ is a torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module which is not free?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

> Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module which is not free?

This is an exercise (page 94) in the book by Hartley and Hawkes.

It is apparent that it is torsion-free. But how to prove that it is not free?

Comment: Given any two elements $r,s\in\mathbb Q$, there are integers $n$ and $m$ such that $nr=ms$.  I don't think that's true in a free abelian group.

Answer (score 1):

Given any two elements $r,s\in\mathbb Q$, there are integers $n$ and $m$ such that $nr=ms$.  I don't think that's true in a free abelian group.

If you have two generators of a free abelian group, $a$ and $b$, then they generate a subgroup like $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ and in there $na$ never equals $mb$, when $a=(1,0)$ and $b=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

No two rational numbers are linearly independent: if $x=\dfrac ab,\;y=\dfrac cd$, you have:
$$bc x-ad y=0.$$

Actually this is true in a more general context: if $S$ is a multiplicative set in a commutative ring $A$, the ring of fractions $S^{-1}A$, albeit a flat $A$-module,  is never a free $A$-module, unless $A=S^{-1}A$, i.e. $S$ is made up of units in $A$.